# Suppose $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are three vertices of a parallelogram. Find vertex $z_4$, which is opposite of $z_2$. Where all $z_i$ are complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Here is my approach: 
Suppose the parallelogram is in the first quadrant.  Then, we can say that $z_1=x_1+iy_1$, $z_2=x_2+iy_2$, and $z_3=x_3+iy_3$.  Let $z_1$ be in bottom left, $z_2$ be in top left, $z_3$ be in top right.  We know that opposite sides of a parallelogram are parallel and congruent.  Then, $z_4=[x_1+|x_3-x_2|]+iy_1$.
Now, to continue, I would consider a parallelogram that is totally contained in each quadrant, then start looking at the cases where the parallelogram is partly contained in quadrant..... this seems like a lot of cases.  I was wondering if there would be an elementary way that I could generalize this problem down to a few cases, or even just a single case.  Thank you.

Comment: Um, more or less.   I think from that I can see how this reduces down and we only consider the "one" case.  As always, thank you, Martin!

Comment: I was surprised that someone downvoted the OP's query.  I thought that his query showed reasonable work but that he was stuck on cartesian rather than polar coordinates.  Therefore, I upvoted his query back.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with and upvoted Martin R's comment and tomi's answer.  My *answer* is intended to provide an alternate way of developing the OP's **intuition**, which may have been the point of the problem.

Every non-zero complex number can be expressed as $\;re^{i\theta} = r[\cos \,\theta + i\sin \,\theta],\;$  where $\,r\,$ is the magnitude of the number, and $\;\theta\;$ represents the angle between the non-zero complex number and the origin.  For $\;z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4\;$ to form a parallelogram, with $\,z_4\,$ opposite of $\,z_2,\,$ two things must happen:

(1) The magnitude of $\;(z_4 - z_1)\;$ = the magnitude of $\;(z_3 - z_2).$ 
(2) The angle formed by the vector $\;(z_4 - z_1)\;$ = the angle formed by the vector $\;(z_3 - z_2).$

Therefore, if $\;(z_3 - z_2)\; = \;re^{i\theta},\;$ then $\;(z_4 - z_1)\;$ must also = $\;re^{i\theta}.$

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this!  This makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the complex numbers as being position vectors.

The vector going from $z_2$ to $z_3$ is $z_3-z_2$.

The vector going from $z_2$ to $z_1$ is $z_1-z_2$.

Because it's a parallelogram, the vector going from $z_2$ to $z_4$ is the sum of those two vectors, which is $z_3-z_2+z_1-z_2=z_3+z_1-2z_2$.

The position vector of $z_4$ is given by $z_2+z_3+z_1-2z_2=z_3+z_1-z_2$.